# Vanilla JavaScript OnBlur/LostFocus For Compsite Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET CompositeControl that I need to react to loss of focus. I've tried various techniques to try and get it to respond, but have had no luck. The control consists of a text box, label, and button. I can get it to post back from leaving the text box, but I need it to respond to the button as well. It has to be a vanilla JavaScript solution, because not all applications that will have this control have jQuery included. I've scoured for answers and haven't been able to find a solution that works.

Is there a way to trigger a post back from the entire composite control container element, or is there a way to attach 'blur' events to elements that don't normally have them?

Comment: Focus and blur are characteristics of input controls usually, not containers or other such elements.  You could attach a blur event to every control inside your composite.

Comment: Wrap everything in another element, a div or similar, and use that as the trigger?

Comment: I've tried the individual controls themselves. The problem there is that if the button blurs, it will trigger the toggling action which will result in a bad user experience. It's kind of like a custom, button triggered privacy field. The user can toggle the text with the button to view/edit it. If the button blurs as they go to the text box, the text will hide itself again.

Comment: @wazz I've tried that, but the div doesn't have any focus events I can cling to in the post back from everything I've read. I know jQuery has that .blur() method that I believe you can use with almost any DOM element, but it's not an option. I've had difficulty in finding a plain JS solution similar to that.

Comment: You have a button that toggles visibility, but your original question says you want the button to cause a postback. Sounds like you need a second button for the postback and/or a slightly different UI approach.

Comment: Well, the UI needs to have a mechanism to toggle for the user. We need it to hide the data without user interaction. The problem here is that my client side info is pretty stripped down because we don't even want to send the contained info unless the user has access rights to it, so it needs to post back to retrieve the data.